# Onset of aggression towards mother

Tags: pre-schooler, pregnancy, anger

I am a mother with 4.5 year old daughter. I am also expecting a second child and am in the second trimester.
Ever since we shared the news with the daughter, she became much more needy. We talk a lot and treat with respect but nevertheless she needs me more. My husband had to stop reading books to her before sleep because she started rejecting this previously standard practice.

Recently she, who is really calm, started to have anger issues that results in her hitting us with her fists. For example, when we say no to cartoons, she becomes visibly angry and becomes aggressive. We don't punish her for such actions, but ask her to stop hitting us and maybe consider going and drawing her feelings. She most often agrees and after drawing flowers or colouring something, says that she does not know what happened.

A week back she did it in public for the first time leaving us startled.

We think her feelings has something to do with the new baby, however we also cannot dismiss generic anger issues which my husband has (albeit, he dealt with it and my daughter has never seen him angry)

**The ask:**

What resources (books, studies) could I use to understand what is going on?
How to deal with it? We are against punishment apart from showing that we are upset because it is normal that she has a lot of emotions

Comment: Going from being single child to having siblings is a big change. How does your daughter handle (big) changes in general?

Comment: She tends to articulate her feelings pretty well. Some examples are:
* Dog death - she cried for a bit and now a year later sometimes remembers with melancholy and says she misses the dog, but there were no spikes
* us moving from Canada home to Europe - she was sad about leaving her friends, but there were no tantrums, she was ok